# Did Puppeteer get an update recently? Because it's been breaking a lot

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium

I do some stuff on repl.it and recently I've been getting error involving chrome r594312 and a failed download, and I resolved it by just starting a new repl and copying the code (I often don't care about the reasoning, just if it works at the end).

> ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r818858! Set
> "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.

<strike>Something along the lines of this with a couple more errors.  Now I thought this was just a me problem until I found out the puppeteer demo was broken too.    https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/  I mean, I fixed the issue temporarily for myself but I'm kinda curious what the reasoning for it is.</strike>  this is no longer the case, but the error on the demo was

> Error running your code. TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is r594312